# Adding unique class name to dynamically created elements/ JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have ten divs created dynamically, each one given the class name 'createdDiv' on creation. How can I iterate through them after they are created and add a unique class name to each?

Somthing like,

```
for each('.createdDiv'){
    var count = 1;
        this.addClass('uniqueName' + count);
        count ++;
}
```

So I would like to end up with 10 divs as follows,

```
('.createdDiv .uniqueName1')
('.createdDiv .uniqueName2')
('.createdDiv .uniqueName3')
('.createdDiv .uniqueName4')
```

and so on...

Comment: Because I'm asking to do it after creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.createdDiv').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('uniqueName' + i);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated! I'll accept the answer 'in 4 minutes'. Cheers!

Comment: you're missing an `);`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.createdDiv').addClass(function (i) {
    return 'uniqueName' + (i + 1)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/347fH/)

Comment: Same question I asked Roko, why add one to the index?

Comment: @j08691 just because OPs index started from 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.createDiv').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('uniqueName'+ (i+1));
});
```

Comment: Just curious, why add one to the index?

Comment: @j08691 cause `index` is `0` based, now take a look at the example in question... thought was correct

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, I just didn't know if there was any reason for doing it, other than to mimic the numbering in the question.

Comment: @j08691 well if he's adding numbered classes than I suppose it matters... but yes, '0' is also a number :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you're asking for, but another way to later access a list of generated elements would be to use the data attribute:

```
$(".createDiv").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("data-index", i);
});
```

Then to select an element based on it's index:

```
$(".createDiv[data-index='" + i + "']")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Oli414/7b9c9xyh/)